ScriptSigSize fdf501
I am trying to understand what scriptsigsize is. If I look at this transaction, the scriptsigsize of the first input would be "fdf501"? If I convert it to decimal, it cannot be the scriptsigsize as the number being too big. It must mean something else?
https://mempool.space/tx/76f268719c41dd5ccf693e84cd0c05cfb6b360fe3158f3311712eb6118c00d7a
If I throw this to a Transaction Splitter, here is the output:
{
  "version": "01000000",
  "inputcount": "07",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "txid": "ece6b5e31d3cd1b9c06f1f270175a5d9106a61bcea2afa9954f02ff6701fd29f",
      "vout": "06000000",
      "scriptsigsize": "fdf501",
      "scriptsig": "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",
      "sequence": "ffffffff"
    },
    {
      "txid": "59c1369f7288c02265c33f0e38d5cdd233cc565d03c47be87da69bc0fb014f05",
      "vout": "11000000",
      "scriptsigsize": "fdf301",
      "scriptsig": "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",
      "sequence": "ffffffff"
    },
    {
      "txid": "cd861e3e1c3fc043346d14f162fe184b3dbb1f5f40ef4b72c965915e00aed687",
      "vout": "12000000",
      "scriptsigsize": "fdf401",
      "scriptsig": "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",
      "sequence": "ffffffff"
    },
    {
      "txid": "f939c2b1fde5d7d55a7c372557c67eafb5895b4650c3d91d899bad1fc95d8ea9",
      "vout": "01000000",
      "scriptsigsize": "fdf401",
      "scriptsig": "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",
      "sequence": "ffffffff"
    },
    {
      "txid": "cdf141f520b5414ea28fee1c76b7b33c309fe3f57055a85ced1b1b72574f2853",
      "vout": "01000000",
      "scriptsigsize": "fdf301",
      "scriptsig": "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",
      "sequence": "ffffffff"
    },
    {
      "txid": "cdf141f520b5414ea28fee1c76b7b33c309fe3f57055a85ced1b1b72574f2853",
      "vout": "00000000",
      "scriptsigsize": "fdf401",
      "scriptsig": "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",
      "sequence": "ffffffff"
    },
    {
      "txid": "bde804a75619e06f68ba9215ae1b925766eeed76adce6fa9c637cd76563d147b",
      "vout": "00000000",
      "scriptsigsize": "fdf401",
      "scriptsig": "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",
      "sequence": "ffffffff"
    }
  ],
  "outputcount": "02",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "amount": "00d0ed902e000000",
      "scriptpubkeysize": "17",
      "scriptpubkey": "a914918611b2a768253b9399b9337de22cf547a5d48c87"
    },
    {
      "amount": "93c396ef00000000",
      "scriptpubkeysize": "17",
      "scriptpubkey": "a914c09637d27fd25c90b74392e12fbf0b17002da69087"
    }
  ],
  "locktime": "00000000"
}

